# How to fetch Data from multiple tables in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables

A User table with column names (UserId,Name,email)

A Videos table with column names (UserId,VideoLink)

An Activity table with column names (UserId,Status) if status=0 likes,if status=1 disliked

I want to get the following result

**Name**, **Total_Videos_posted_by_that_user**, **count(Likes)**, **count(dislikes)**

How can i Query them in a single Query?

Comment: you;re looking for JOIN http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 3):

```
select u.name, 
       videocount, 
       dislikes,
       likes
from user u
left join 
(
  select u.name, count(v.videolink) as videocount
  from user u
  inner join videos v on v.userid = u.userid
) x on x.name = u.name
left join 
(
  select u.name, 
         sum(a.status=1) as dislikes,
         sum(a.status=0) as likes
  from user u
  inner join activity a on a.userid = u.userid
) y on y.name = u.name
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d4c8/9)

Comment: Are you sure that sum(status=1) or count(a.Status=1)?

Comment: I am getting correct data if i use 
select u.name,count(v.videolink) as videocount
from user u left join videos on u.userid=v.userid group by u.Name

If i include another table as you mentioned activity, It gives incorrect result

Comment: I am sure it is `sum(status=1)` You want to count the dislikes only, right?

Comment: Ya i want to count both dislikes and likes. Ok even though i try to get dislikes count as you mentioned it returns incorrect data. Example user name John have 19 videos if i query till video count. If i include Dislikes query then it shows 142 as video count. and unfortunately dislikes count is also showing 142. But thats not the correct data it should be 6

Comment: It says Column 'Status' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Waahh what a brilliant way of approach you suggested. That logic was awesome. let me try now. many thanks